# Implementing a https server on sailjs

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https, sails.js

Hi I am creating some rest api for sailjs application. Now I need to access my application using OAuth2.0 authentication with http-bearer-token strategy. So I want my server to accept https connection. Any hint how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be pretty simple, actually. Update your `config/local.js` with the following:

```
/**
 * Depencencies
 */
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  // Here go the port, environment definitions, etc.
  // ...

  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('path_to_your_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path_to_your_cert.pem')
  }
};
```

To play with it in development environment, you can just [create a self-signed certificate](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server), put those files in `config/ssl` and in `config/local.js` use

```
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'ssl/key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'ssl/cert.pem')
  }
```

Comment: Hi Bredikin it worked, now I am facing couple of other issue. 
1) I want to run both http and https at the same time in sails.js any hints regarding that. 
2) I am using a self signed certificate with that. Which I showed to my commputer and it is working in postman and chrome but I wrote a mocha test suite which stopped working with SSL any idea how I can force mocha to ignore SSL security parameter.

Comment: @VampireCoder I would really recommend you create two more questions for those, since those are interesting topics and the answers would be hard to format within a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the production environment, we should not let the nodejs app face the raw traffic. Use Nginx instead, Nginx can handle the https connection and forward to sailjs http connection, additional handle the rate limit, cache...

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/your_site/your_site-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/your_site/your_site.key;

    location /your_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

It also handles the http and https connections in the same time. In the sample below, I just forward http connection to https. If you have another purpose, just change the logic inside.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```